# Separating a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string that looks like:

```
"EXP001,1,#,*\r\n\r\nEXP001,2,#,*\r\n\r\n"
```

How do I separate the two strings to make:

```
string1 = "EXP001,1,#"
string2 = "EXP001,2,#"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
str1, str2 = str.delete("\r\n").split(",*")
#str1 => "EXP001,1,#"
#str2 => "EXP001,2,#"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
string1, string2 = s.gsub(',*','').split
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same in multiple ways. If the format of the string is fixed, the most efficient way would be with regex,

```
"EXP001,1,#,*\r\n\r\nEXP001,2,#,*\r\n\r\n".scan(/EXP\d+,\d+,#/)
=> string1, string2 = ["EXP001,1,#", "EXP001,2,#"]
```